# What are the "$@n" variables in the ".output" files?

Tags: bison

My ".output" file from bison has many dozens of variables named like $@1, $@2, ..., $@38. These are somehow associated with mid-actions rules, which the grammar I'm examining has a lot of, but in a way I have yet to fully discern. They are representing non-terminal symbols, somehow related to the mid-action rules. That's about all I can tell.

EDIT:

---

input.y (cartoon version):

```
%start  statement

%%

statement:  /* empty */ { print("testA"); }
    |   ';'         { print("testB"); }
    |       statement   { print("testC"); } thing1 thing2 { print("testD"); }
    ;
```

---

input.output (cartoon version):

```
0 $accept: statement $end

1 statement: /* empty */
2      | ';'

3 $@1: /* empty */

4 statement: statement $@1 thing1 thing2

10 thing1: /*empty*/
20 thing2: /*empty*/
```

Comment: OK, I looked into this some more, and edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a mid-rule action in a rule is almost exactly the same as adding a non-terminal with an empty right-hand-side and the same action (now a final action), except for the numbering of the semantic values in the action. (bison lets you refer to semantic values before the beginning of the production with negative indices; this is the mechanism used for mid-rule actions, except that bison computes the stack offsets for you.)

The inserted empty non-terminals are "named" `@1, @2, ...`. You'll see these in the state descriptions; it will look like every mid-rule action has been replaced by an `@i` placeholder (which is in fact what has happened).

**Edit**

It turns out that mid-rule actions might be named `$@n` or `@n`. According to a helpful comment in `reader.c` at line 527 (in v2.6.5, which is the latest release as I write):

```
  /* If the midrule's $$ is set or its $n is used, remove the `$' from the
     symbol name so that it's a user-defined symbol so that the default
     %destructor and %printer apply.  */
```

In other words, a mid-rule action will have a `$` in its name precisely if it does not have any value (it neither sets the value nor does anyone use the value); if it has a value (and I guess mine almost always do), then it will not have a `$` in its name.

Mystery solved, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Up to Bison 2.3, the mid-rule action's anonymous symbol was named `@N`, but it was changed in Bison 2.4 into `$@N`.  See http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bison-patches/2006-10/msg00075.html

Bottom line is: if you see `@N`, it's high time to update your copy of Bison :)

Comment: that's not correct. You'll find @N in .output files generated by bison 2.6.5 (and I have no idea what the relevance of the patch you mentioned is, but it's ancient history anyway). The key is the comment at reader.c:527 (in v2.6.5). (I was motivated to check this because I have an almost up-to-date bison, and it showed me `@N` names.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!  FWIW, the documentation of Bison 2.7 clarifies this point: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Mid_002dRule-Action-Translation